# how to convert Oracle geometry to SQL GEOMETRY

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, geometry

Ihave some geometry datatype entries in one of my table in a Oracle database.I would need to import those data into a sql server table to then use them for something else. I am aware that I cannot do that with an ssis package.There might also be some conversion problems.Could you point me in the right direction for how to do this correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd bet dollars to donuts that you *can* use SSIS for this, with a little coercion. Specifically, well-known text (WKT) is the standard representation for geospatial data. On the Oracle side, you can use `Get_WKT()` against your data to return the WKT. Then on the SQL side, you can use `STGeomFromText()` and use the results of it to insert it. Use SSIS to stitch it all together and you've got it.

Comment: Do you know how to use those methods. Could you give me an example of refer me to an exemple for beginners.Thanks

Comment: Well... I don't know Oracle, but the documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_objrelschema.htm suggests it would be `select your_column.Get_WKT() from your_Table`. And on the SQL Side, it'd be `insert into your_table (your_column) values (geometry::STGeomFromText(@wkt, 0))` where `@wkt` holds the well-known text. I'd suggest trying both in isolation before trying to wire up with SSIS.

Comment: it does not work for me because I use 3d  geometry. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what issues you're having, so it's hats for me to give recommendations. But either SQL supports 3D objects or it doesn't. Find the answer to that to move forward.